# Bootstrap expanded collapsible menu covered in xs grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I view this site on mobile or shrink the browser size until the xs grid takes effect, the expanded collapsible menu links (below "RESIDENTIAL") are covered by the slideshow div. Is there an easy fix for this? Can't crack it for the life of me.

Site example: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/process.html

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Studio Green</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Typekit custom fonts -->
    <script src="//use.typekit.net/bcn3ife.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

    <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom icons -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fonts/flexslider-icon.eot">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- row 1: static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </div><!-- navbar toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- container -->
    </nav><!-- navbar -->

    <!-- row 2: body -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">

            <!-- sidebar -->
                <aside class="navbar-collapse collapse panel-group col-lg-3 col-med-4 col-sm-4" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                          RESIDENTIAL
                    </li>
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT <span class="spaced">1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">3</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">4</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">5</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">6</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">7</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">8</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">9</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">10</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="schools.html">
                      SCHOOLS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="parks.html">
                      PARKS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="hospitality.html">
                      HOSPITALITY
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                      ELEMENTS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">ENTRY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">FENCES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">FIRE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">LIGHTING</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">PAVING</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="plants.html">PLANTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">POOLS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SEATING</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SCULPTURE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">STAIRS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SUSTAINABILITY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">WATER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </aside>

            <!-- slideshow gallery -->          
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                <div class="flexslider">
                  <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_01.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_02.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_03.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                          Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                          Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                          Exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_04.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_05.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_06.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_07.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_08.jpg" />
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- address -->
            <address>232 SIR FRANCIS DRAKE BLVD</br>
            SAN ANSELMO, CA 94960</br>
            415 721 0905</address>
        </div><!--/row -->
    </div><!--/container -->


    <!-- javaspcript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade"
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* this is a custom css stylesheet */


/* ==========================================================================
   Base Styles, Bootstrap Modifications & Fonts Import
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.container {
    width: 100%;
}


.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.img-centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mt-lg {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.mt {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.mb {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.drop {
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.spaced {
    margin-left: 37px;
}

.sm-spaced {
    margin-left: 5px;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   General styles
   ========================================================================== */

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #555;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

a {
    color: #555;
    outline: 0;
}

.strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
}

small {
    color: #555;
}

aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

address {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    float: right;
    padding: 90px 0px 30px 15px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}

.email {
    color: #6CAA3D;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.info-box {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 60px 20px 0 15px;
}

.info-box p {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.info-box h5 {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.contact {
    height: auto!important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 315px;
}

.team-box img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Navigation styles
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Top nav section
 */

.navbar-header {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}

.navbar .nav {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #555;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .active > a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    color: #6CAA3D;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: -65px;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.navbar-right {
    padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
}

/*
 * Left aside nav
 */

.panel {
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    margin: 45px 0 0 100px;
}

.panel-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    list-style: none;
}

.panel-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.panel-body {
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.panel-body ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.panel-body ul li {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.panel-group {
    text-align: left;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border-top:0px;
}

.nav-caret {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 8px;
}

/*
 * flexslider format
 */

.flexslider{
    background:none!important;
    border:none!important;
    box-shadow:none!important;
    margin:0px -15px 0px 0px!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.flex-direction-nav a  {
    color: #999!important;
}

.flex-next { 
    padding-right: 40px!important;
}

.flex-control-nav {
    text-align: right!important;
    padding-right: 70px!important;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
    color: transparent!important;
}

.nodot .flex-control-paging li a { 
    display: none!important;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
    background: #6CAA3D!important;
}

.right {
    padding-top: 100%!important;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btm {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.l {
    left: 0;
}

.r {
    right: 0;
}

.w {
    width: 100%!important;
    left: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px!important;
}

.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 300px;
}

.flex-caption p {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.carousel .slides > li {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Its not covered but by default `.collapse` has display:none. In CSS give `.navbar-collapse.collapse {display: block !important;}`, it will be visible.

Comment: True, but the problem is that the lower links in the expanded menu (in the xs grid view) are unclickable and covered by the slideshow div. I'm looking for a workaround for this. Sorry if this was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of floats

Adding `pull-left` to the parent of `<div class="flexslider">` will fix the issue

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 pull-left"> <!-- add pull-left 
    <div class="flexslider">
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you for saving me a headache

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have 2 problem.

first:left Side Menu covered by the slideshow div

Second:Side Menu go on Top Menu when view on mobile

for first problem why you not use Just "col-md-4" for aside tag and  "col-md-8" for Slid?
i checked that's work

and for second i think better use "navbar-default" Instead of "navbar-collapse"

 Of course if you think that is a problem.